# Results from iClose() in MQL4 are not advancing with timeshift - why?

Tags: mql4

Sirs,

In connection with another problem, I am trying to create an array whose contents are the previous hourly closing values of the EURUSD.  I have code as follows:

```
      void Trade()
      {
         double longThresh     = this.longThreshold;
         double longTP         = this.longTakeProfit;
         double longSL         = this.longStopLoss;
         double shortThresh    = this.shortThreshold;
         double shortTP        = this.shortTakeProfit;
         double shortSL        = this.shortStopLoss;

         int dummyIndex = 0;
         Print( "Triggered reload of stack data for trading routine" );

         this.stackArray[0] = iClose( "EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 1 );
         this.stackArray[1] = iClose( "EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 2 );
         this.stackArray[2] = iClose( "EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 3 );
         this.stackArray[3] = iClose( "EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 4 );
         this.stackArray[4] = iClose( "EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 5 );
         this.stackArray[5] = iClose( "EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 6 );
         this.stackArray[6] = iClose( "EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 7 );
         this.stackArray[7] = iClose( "EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 8 );

         this.PrintStackArray();
         }
```

The function above is actually an object method. The Object is instantiated, and a **`do-while`** loop causes the method above to be re-executed every hour at the five minute mark.

The problem is that when the code above executes an hour later, the **`PrintStackArray()`** output indicates that the **`iClose()`** function is not keeping up with new candlesticks every hour.

To put it another way, if the code were to execute at 5:05, it would give the same output as it would at 6:05, and in turn give identical output at 7:05.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why re-executing the `iClose()` functions does not update the array with the new candlestick values.  Despite over two weeks of tinkering with this issue, I cannot force my EA to update and recognize new candlestick values.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen uder such condition,
that the code was being run without a live-feed of events from market, using just a localhost time-bound triggered Object method invocation [( which was not disclosed as an **`MCVE`** above )](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) thus forever showing the same time-series data head, which under such conditions simply get no live-feed updates, yielding the same [1,2,3,..] values forever:

```
if ( !IsConnected() )
{     Print( "No connection!" );
      return( 0 );
      }
```

may validate your EA state against a live server.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  In the event that I validate my EA state against the live server and find out that there is no live feed, how to I re-establish a live feed?  In essence, how do I fix the problem so that I can get continuous live-feed data?

Comment: Because of the uncontrollable levels of risk of mis-use, all the connection / login activities are restricted to a set of manual, human-to-broker, interactions ( login identity, trading-server selection,access-credentials provisioning ). So such an exception-handler may send you an email, but a live human being has to click and assist the Terminal to re-log-in.